# HttpClient request returns status 410 Gone

Tags: c#, web-crawler, dotnet-httpclient

I'm practicing my skills with httpclient .NET 4.5 , but I ran into some trouble trying to get html content from a webpage which I can view no problem with my browser, but I will get a 410 Gone when I use httpclient
There is the first page that I can actually get with httpclient
https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_detail_sched?term_in=201610&crn_in=20172

But links inside of this above url, like the url represented by "View Catalog Entry "

when I try to access with httpclient, I will get a 410 Gone. 
I used Tuple to set up the series of requests

```
var requests = new List<Tuple<Httpmethod, string, FormUrlEncodedContent, string>>()
        {
            new Tuple<Httpmethod, string, FormUrlEncodedContent, string>(Httpmethod.GET, "https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_detail_sched?term_in=201610&crn_in=20172", null, ""),
            new Tuple<Httpmethod, string, FormUrlEncodedContent, string>(Httpmethod.GET, "https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckctlg.p_display_courses?term_in=201610&one_subj=EPCS&sel_crse_strt=10100&sel_crse_end=10100&sel_subj=&sel_levl=&sel_schd=&sel_coll=&sel_divs=&sel_dept=&sel_attr=", null, ""),
            new Tuple<Httpmethod, string, FormUrlEncodedContent, string>(Httpmethod.GET, "https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckctlg.p_disp_listcrse?term_in=201610&subj_in=EPCS&crse_in=10100&schd_in=%", null, "")

        };
```

Then use the foreach to loop through pass each element in requests to a function

```
 HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            CookieContainer = cookies,
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
        };
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler as HttpMessageHandler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(url),
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000)
        };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("keep-alive");
        if (referrer.Length > 0)
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = new Uri(referrer);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Navigating to '" + url + "...");
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        //List<Cookie> cook = GetAllCookies(cookies);
        try
        {
            switch (method)
            {
                case Httpmethod.POST:
                    result = await client.PostAsync(url, post_content);
                    break;
                case Httpmethod.GET:
                    result = await client.GetAsync(url);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
        }
```

I have no clue what is wrong with my method, since I have successfully handled requests that needs to be logged in with this method.
I intended to build some sort of web crawler using this.
Please help, thanks in advance.

I forgot to mention, the links inside of the above url could be accessed by clicking on them on a web browser, simply copy them to address bar will get 410 Gone as well.

EDIT: There is some JavaScript code I saw in page source, it's creating an XMLHttpRequest to get the content, so it might be that it only refresh part of the page instead of creating a new webpage. But the url is changed. How do I get httpclient do the clicking thing?

Comment: so your crawler behaves the same as your browser. What's wrong with that?

Comment: This is a message sent from the server, it doesn't have anything to do with HttpClient. At some point, the server returned 410. Right now, the links work

Comment: If the link addresses don't work even on a browser, I suppose the anchors have JS onclick handlers that redirect to the right place

Comment: The date on the catalog page is May 29. I suspect you tried to access a catalog that had just expired and is now ... gone and never coming back. The new catalog is now available so no more 410 until it expires as well

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I suspect that the page is created when I click the link, If you try not clicking the the link and get the url from page source, try copy it to web browser it will give you 410 Gone, if you click it then you get the next webpage.

Comment: @Martijn maybe I didn't make myself very clear.. The browser will get what I wanted when I click the links, but you see I can't make the crawler as smart as a human being...

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I tried a load of times, using httpclient only gets me 410 Gone. I logged it with chrome developer tool, by clicking the link it is just a http get request...

Comment: A web request with some cookies. Perhaps the server is checking for specific cookies and returns 410 if they are missing

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Well, I checked cookies with chrome, they appears to be the same before and after I click the link. Plus, the variable cookies is in class scope, so it will store cookies whatever I get from the last request

Comment: Use Postman to see the actual response message. HttpRequestException does not give the exact Message.